# "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" when building Cordova App

Tags: cordova, build

Problem while building Cordova application. What did I do wrong?

OS: Ubuntu Bionic (LTS) 64 bit

ANT: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.3 compiled on July 19 2018

Cordova: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Gradle: Gradle 4.10.3

JRE: java version "1.8.0_201"

ANDROID_TARGET: 28, 26

```
cordova build android
```

After running the command, I got error as follows:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/mosta/android-studio/tools (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/www/html/mobile/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 55s
/var/www/html/mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/www/html/mobile/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 55s
```